# Returning a path with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Well I have a method to return a path, by `JFileChooser`, I want to save that path in a variable to then modify an `File`. But when I call the method in  `JFrame` button with line: `tf.guardarTareasHash(operator.obtenerTabla(), "modificar", tf.path());`, I realize that I opens the `FileDialog` again to select the File.

I wanted to use `tf.path()` to send like a parameter, but I didn't expect that it would be opening an JFileChooser again. The line `operator.obtenerTabla()` sends an `Hashtable` and *modificar* is a `String` that I send for cheking in the conditional if the program will save a new file or modify.

```
    public String path(){
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new 
        File("C:\\Users\\ARCANET\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\hash\\tareas"));
        jfc.showOpenDialog(jfc);
        String ruta = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();        
        return ruta;
}
```

¿Is there anyway to store the path of the selected file without open the `OpenDialog` again? I thought of making an `static` variable for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want

```
tf.guardarTareasHash(operator.obtenerTabla(), "modificar", tf.path());
```

not to open the file dialog again. In this case you need to store the result of your path-method the first time you are calling it and passing the result later on as the third parameter instead of calling the path-method again.

```
class MyClass {
    String myPath = null;
    ...
    // call the path method which opens the file dialog
    myPath = path();
    ...
    // use the saved result
    tf.guardarTareasHash(operator.obtenerTabla(), "modificar", myPath);
}
```

You still have to implement checks what to do if `myPath` is not initialized (e.g. user cancels the file dialog)

Comment: Well, I made something different I saved the path loaded in an ´jLabel´ for then passing like a parameter with getting text from the component label. But ´myPath´ needs to be `static` for it works otherwise the value doesn't save.